# How to resize lock-screen background using the command line on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen, desktop-background, resize

What the title says. The command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options "scaled"
```

works for the desktop, but obviously not for the lock screen. I have no idea what the schema for the lock-screen is, and don't really know where to look for it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-options "scaled"
```